# Can we change the values of presentation variable in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, powerbi, tableau-api, obiee

I want to pass the value from one analysis to another analysis. Can I use presentation variable for this purpose? If not what else can I use

Comment: With this minimal information we cannot hep you. Pleaes read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

A presentation variable can be set by prompts, not an analysis. To pass a value it depends on the kind of action you have in place to go from analysis A to B. If it's a custom built link you can add the value as filter in the URL, if it's a navigation you can use the columns of the analysis A which are sent automatically by the link etc.

Keeping it short: no, your analysis A can't set a presentation variable for analysis B, you must use a prompt to set it or use an alternative way of sending values via the navigation.